# Beamer: how to set no style for blocks?

Tags: beamer, block

for my presentation I using the Rochester theme.
I like this theme except for the blocks style.
I need to have no style for this enviroment.

How can I set no style for blocks, using the theme anyway?

Comment: all block *have* style. if you not liked one provided with selected theme, than you need to change this style. welcome to tex.se.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid drawing the rectangles in the background, you can set the background color of the block body to white. You can do that by writing the following code in the preamble after loading the theme:

```
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=white}
```

If can also do that for the block title. However, in this case you must also set a the foreground (text) color, because it is white by default in the theme. The following code sets the background color of the block title, for example, to black:

```
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=white,fg=black}
```

You could also employ a color from the theme; to use the `structure` color, you may write:

```
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,bg=white,fg=structure.fg}
```

I hope it helps.

**Edit** As pointed out by @samcarter [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393022/beamer-how-to-set-no-style-for-blocks/393036#comment976645_393036), instead of a white background it is better to make it transparent, so that it works also if the frame background is not white, by using:

```
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=,fg=black}
```

Comment: Maybe replace the white with `\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=}` so the background becomes transparent - makes it easier to use your solution in case of frames with a coloured background.

Comment: You are right. The theme in the question has a white background; however, for future reference your suggestion is certainly better. Should I edit the answer and add it?

Comment: Feel free to add the suggestion to your answer.